# How does a semaphore actually work when all N processes are inside the critical section?

Tags: linux, synchronization, operating-system, mutex, semaphore

As far as I understand, a mutex is used to lock the critical section so that no other threads can access it when already a thread is using it. So mutex avoids multiple threads trying to use or change the data at a time. But semaphore allows N number of threads to enter the critical section and starts blocking from N+1.. Wont the N threads try to change the data at at time when they are inside the critical section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, you are violating the concept of a critical section.  I don't see your point.  But yes is the answer - N threads/LWP's will all be pounding away at the same time, producing undefined behavior.

Comment: The [producer consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)#Example:_Producer.2Fconsumer_problem) is a common example for when a semaphore might be used. The semaphore only allows `n` threads to be in the critical section at once... it can also tell each thread which "number" they are. In that way they can partition the set of `n` resources without conflict. But there are surely other situations where `n` threads (but no more) can be doing whatever they want in a section without `n` resources...